# Firefox Driver don't save sessions and cookies in profile

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using firefox for an altomation which I need to keep login always active, ie .. keep the session, cookies etc ..
I'm setting a default user for selenium not to create temporary, but it seems like Firefox ignores and clears session, cookies, history, everything .. every time it is terminated ..
In the chrome driver is working perfectly informing a default profile, but unfortunately I can not use the chrome.

Is there any solution for this?

```
public IWebDriver StartFirefoxDriver(string url, string driverLocation, bool headless = false)
{
    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverLocation, "geckodriver.exe");
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
    service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

    var test = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\gabriels\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\zq9sf3jp.Whats");
    test.DeleteAfterUse = false;

    var firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();

    firefoxOptions.Profile = test;

    if (headless)
        firefoxOptions.AddArgument("--headless");


    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, firefoxOptions);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);



    return driver;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your default profile session that you personally use for personal activities.

```
            FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfileManager().GetProfile("default-release");
            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.Profile = profile;
            IWebDriver firefox = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            firefox.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie("key", "value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The location where I was taking the profile was incorrect, it's a lesson for anyone who is making the same mistake.

The correct location is:

> C:\Users\gabriels\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\